# Finding part of string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm pretty new in Python and don't really know regex. I've got some strings like:

```
a = "Tom Hanks XYZ doesn't really matter"
b = "Julia Roberts XYZ don't worry be happy"
c = "Morgan Freeman XYZ all the best"
```

In the middle of each string there's word XYZ and than some text. I need regex that will find and match this part, more precisely: from XYZ to the end of string.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use regex?  Wouldn't something like `a[a.find("XYZ"):]` work too?

Comment: Oh! you're right :)
I didn't know that it can be done without regex!

Answer (score 2):

Unles there is a specific requirement to do through Regex, a non-regex solution will work fine here.
There are two possible ways you can approach this problem

1.
Given

```
a = "Tom Hanks XYZ doesn't really matter"
```

Partition the string with the separator, preceded with a space

```
''.join(a.partition(" XYZ")[1:])[1:]
```

Please note, if the separator string does not exist this will return a empty string.

2.

```
a[a.index(" XYZ") + 1:]
```

This will raise an exception `ValueError: substring not found` if the string is not found

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression

```
(XYZ.*)
```

What this does is start capturing when it sees the letters "XYZ" and matches anything beyond that zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = re.search("(XYZ.*)", a)
```

If you want to show that part of the string:

```
print m.groups()[0]
```